# Unable to link with opencv libraries

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

I trying use OpenCV with visual studio 2017 and running this example code is giving me build time errors

I have provided the right directories to the libraries. I have gone through  many tutorials and questions/answers on stack overflow so many times but haven't succeeded in fixing the problem.

```
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core.hpp"
#include "pch.h"
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
    Mat test = imread("lena.jpg", IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
    imshow("tst", test);
    waitKey();
}
```

I get the following errors

```
C2065 'IMREAD_UNCHANGED':undeclared identifier
C3861 'imread': identifier not found
C3861 'imshow': identifier not found
C3861 'waitkey': identifier not found
```

Intellisense gives me all the library suggestions when I type the code but it throws errors after build.

Comment: Your problem is not about link libraries, it's about includes. The simplest way: #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

Comment: @Nuzhny So you are saying its <> instead of "" ? I made those changes but now it says cv namespace doesn't exist

Comment: Put your includes after `#include "pch.h"` and it should start working.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. The error got solved.